# Bash Conditional Odd Behavior

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I am trying to evaluate this conditional, which I know is True. I can even echo the expression and get True.

I've tried many many flavors of brackets, assigning the command to a variable and other things.

```sh
    if $(az group exists --name $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)
    then
        exit 1
    else

        az group create --location $LOCATION --name $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME
    fi
```

even though this command is true on the command line, it fails the conditional in the script.

```sh
az group exists --name $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME
```

It always creates the group

Comment: Where do you run the script?

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea what `az` does but I suspect you meant to write

```
if az group exists --name $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME
```

to test the exit status of `az` rather than

```
if $(az group exists --name $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)
```

which tests the exit status of executing the text printed to stdout by `az`. Look:

```
$ if echo 1; then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi
1
success

$ if $(echo 1); then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi
-bash: 1: command not found
failure

$ if echo date; then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi
date
success

$ if $(echo date); then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi
Wed, May 15, 2019 10:25:26 PM
success
```

Don't use all upper-case for non-exported variables btw and do always quote your variables unless you have a specific **NEED** not to.